# JQuery Email has already register

Tags: php, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Can any body help me.. i have some problem in jquery email validation, i want to check that this email has already registered or not.. i have tried but my code is not working (i.e did not show error message)

here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("add_form").validate( {
       rules: {  
           email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
            remote: "emails.php"
    },
 },
 messages: {
         email:   {
    remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
        }
 },
 });
```

and emails.php file  code here

```
 <?php
$request = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['email']));

require 'db.inc.php';
$db = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD) or
die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));


$query = 'SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email="'.$request.'"';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$valid = 'true';
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
{
    $valid = '"Thats already taken."';
}
echo $valid;

?>
```

Comment: Your SQL is open to injection. You need to sanitise your variables before just dumping them into an SQL statement like this. Please look into using PHPs PDO classes or at least `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: What validation plugin are using for this script?

Comment: you have document ready but you have not closed [end tags/brackets] the tags properly. add `});` at the end of your jQuery

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the response of remote validation is a JSON-encoded boolean, not a JSON-encoded string.

You have "true" or "false", which will become "\"true\"" or "\"false\"" through json_encode(), which is wrong. Actual true or false will become "true" or "false", which is correct.

Setting the response content type to JSON might also be a good idea:

header('Content-type: application/json');